# Owl carousel is showing two images as one (4 images-two dots)

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I'm trying to add a slider to my website use owl carousel.

In `head` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

In `body` at the beginning:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    });
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 1
            },
            1000: {
                items: 1
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

`html`in body:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Result is like this:
[image: 4 images but only two dots appearing]

Even though there are four images, it's showing only 2 dots and the carousel isn't hiding the overflow. The width extends beyond view and is horizontally scrollable(entire page, not the carousel)

Answer (score 0):

Put your script tag in the HTML file above the closing  tag and try this Jquery code:-

```
const responsive = {
100:{
    items: 1
},
320: {
    items: 1
},
560: {
    items: 2
},
1200: {
    items: 3
}
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop: true,
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 2000,
dots: false,
responsive: responsive
});
});

The Second thing is that download jQuery to your PC instead fo taking online CDN